# Collatz Conjecture Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Related: [A general question about the Collatz Conjecture and finding that integer that doesn't work](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201942/a-general-question-about-the-collatz-conjecture-and-finding-that-integer-that-do)

I was coding a solution to the $3k+1$ problem and was looking at ways to speed up the computation. In the related question, it is noted that the first counterexample should be an odd number, and I have adjusted my code to *only* search the odd numbers, immediately disregarding the evens.

Is it valid to stop computing a trajectory once the current value has dropped below the starting point?

Comment: I don't think so. How do you know for sure that $3a + 1$ for whatever $a$ you found less than the start will eventually devolve to 1?

Comment: Unless you've already checked the Collatz conjecture for every number less than your start

Comment: This question is a meaningless. All trajectories so far have proven to eventually converge to $1$. So yes, you can stop computing a trajectory once the current value has dropped below the starting point. But you can just as well stop computing any other trajectory. As to (what I guess is) your point - some trajectories go below the starting point and then back above it long before they finally converge to $1$.

Comment: I concur with @arbitraryusername. If you've already checked all odd values up to $n$, and you drop below $n$, then yes, it is OK to stop computing. But if not, then no. However, you might want to start computing beyond the known range if you really want to make progress i.e. $\approx 5.48\cdot 10^{18}$ as you cite in your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some "independent and unpaid research" on this (much against all advice an undergrad student in mathematics receives regarding this particular problem) and arrived at the following:

*The Collatz conjecture is true if and only if all positive integers of the forms $4r+3$ or $8r+3$, $r$ being odd, eventually reach lower values by iterating the Collatz function.*

So indeed, you may restrict your attention to odd numbers, specifically to those of the form I just mentioned, and drop the computations when they reach lower values.

(My analysis can be pushed even further to filter away more odd numbers that will reach lower points, but I saw no clear pattern in my analysis, hence paused working on it)

A short version of my proof of the above statement: We just show that all other positive integers eventually reach lower values. For even numbers this is clear. For odd numbers, write them in the form $2^kn+1$, $n$ odd and $k>0$. Iterate the Collatz function. For even exponents $k$, 3 iterations will be enough (details left to the reader). For odd exponents other than 1, 3 iterations will again suffice. Thus the conjecture is true iff all positive integers of the form $2n+1$, $n$ odd, reach lower values.

Now, substitute $n$ by $2^xy+1$, $y$ odd and $x>1$, repeat the above analysis.

As for what happens with $4r+3$ and $8r+3$, $r$ odd…I realized that I probably wouldn't be able to finish any kind of proof with this, but that I could go on forever with these substitutions…

Also, as all others have said, please make sure that all integers less than those that you consider have already been verified, otherwise you might fool yourself (even though I feel it wouldn't matter in the long run, but it could cause some delays in finding the truth in those scenarios…).

Comment: A minor update: I looked into the case $8r+3$, $r$ odd, and managed to prove that we can replace that case with the subcase $16r+11$, for $r$ odd, instead. So we must check all integers of the form $4r+3$ and $16r+11$, for odd $r$.

Comment: And by performing my analysis on the $4r+3$ case, we end up with the subcases $xr+7$, for odd $r$ and $x\in \{4,8,16,32,64\}$.

Comment: I don't understand how after the finding, that the set $A=\{4r+3\}_{r \ge 0}$ is a sufficient subset for the analysis of the Collatz-trajectory, there is any need to look at $8r+3$ , $8r+11$ etc which are only *subsets* of the already discussed set $A$...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Good point. I originally thought that this could potentially cut computation time when searching for counterexamples, by trying to find as large increments as possible, but that doesn't really happen in what is outlined in my answer due to the $4r+3$ case (and the analysis on the $4r+3$-case does break into several subcases as indicated in my comment above, probably making this a dead end proof-wise as well as hindering further improvements in computation time). So indeed you are correct in that the $4r+3$-case alone is enough and more efficient than the alternatives for now.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I just realized I forgot that $r$ is stated to be odd in all expressions in my answer, that is we are considering the sets $\{4r+3\}_{r\ \text{odd}}$ and $\{8r+3\}_{r\ \text{odd}}$, not $\{4r+3\}_{r \geq 0}$ (sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough on that point). The two sets I consider are not subsets of each other, and do not form the set $\{4r+3\}_{r \geq 0}$ together. But still, $\{4r+3\}_{r \geq 0}$ is enough for analysis, my answer just tries to go deeper than that to see if anything worthwhile can be found.

Comment: Upps, I missed completely the point of $r$ being odd. Sorry! Good you gave such a detailed comment. Unfortunately I've at the moment not the energy to get deeper into that. If there is some more relevant point in my doubt, perhaps I can come back to this tomorrow or so...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the minimal counterexample, then you could stop as soon as the trajectory reached a number less than itself; since every element in the trajectory of a counterexample is also a counterexample.

However, this should not be confused with, "If the trajectory of $x$ contains $y \lt x$, $x$ is not a counterexample", it is only true that "If the trajectory of $x$ contains $y \lt x$, $x$ is not the **minimal** counterexample".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it valid to stop computing a trajectory once the current value has dropped below the starting point?

Well, your question is impossible to answer, since at present, there is no known starting value which doesn't eventually converge to the circular trajectory of $[4,2,1]$.

So let's say I give you a counterexample where you **cannot** stop computing a trajectory once the current value has dropped below the starting point: $[41,124,62,31]$.

This trajectory is known to converge after $110$ steps ($40$ steps through odd numbers).

If you **don't** know this fact, then my example is good enough to tell you that you **cannot** stop computing the trajectory once the current value has dropped below the starting point.

If you **do** know this fact, then you **can** indeed stop computing the  trajectory once the current value has dropped below the starting point.

But if you already know this fact, then you may as well stop computing the trajectory **right away**.